# Yii2 rest Upload files & auth_key issue

Tags: yii2

I’m implementing a REST controller to upload files from a mobile app. I set the multipart content-type, the files to be sent and the auth_key because security reasons but the problem here is, with multipart/form-data, nothing is arriving, the bodyParam and the post array are empty, while, with rawBody, I get all.

How do I check the auth key inside checkAccess for normal posts and multipart posts?

BTW, I have implemented the multipart/form-data parser-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a clue why, but finally all is working.